# Unable to create a volume with New-Volume in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am getting an invalid parameter error from this command though it was copied right off Microsoft's Technet. Any one see an issue?

```
New-Volume -StoragePoolFriendlyName "Test_Pool" -FriendlyName "test1" -AccessPath "C:\test1" -ResiliencySettingName "Simple" -StorageTiers (Get-StorageTier -FriendlyName "*SSD*"), (Get-StorageTier -FriendlyName "*HDD*") -StorageTierSizes 20GB, 80GB -FileSystem ReFS
```

The directory for the file access path is setup and the storage pool and storage tiers are setup:

[image: Storagepool screenshot]

I've been trying many different ways to run the command, but nothing is working. Error Screenshot:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Please copy and paste in TEXT into the question whatever you think would help someone give a helpful response.

Comment: what version of powershell are you running? $psversiontable

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the answer to this is that New-Volume will not create volumes on SMR HHDs in the ReFS file system. On normal HDDs this would work fine.